# How to bind a custom event to parent element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I am using [angular-resize-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event) tool to listen resize of my items.

So I can listen any  element using `<div (resized)="onResized($event)"></div>`

But I need to use this in my nested component to listen parent.

I am using my `ChartComponent` in my `WidgetComponent` init function like following:

init function of ChartComponent is:

```
ngOnInit() {
     let chartComponent = this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement;
     let widgetContainerComponent = chartComponent.parentElement;
     let cardBody = widgetContainerComponent.parentElement;

     this.renderer.listen(cardBody, 'resized', (event) => {
       console.log(event)
    })
}
```

But this is not working. But if I add click listener, it is working.

```
    this.renderer.listen(cardBody, 'click', (event) => {
       console.log(event)
    })
```

I want to listen parent `resized` event from child component. If parent size change, I will set the width and height of Chart  in child component (ChartComponent).

How can I set `resized` event?

Comment: So you want your child component listen then event from parent?

Comment: I want to listen parent resized event from child component. If parent size change, I will set the Chart of child component.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your child component listen from parent you can use EventEmitter.
An example;

On your child component add an EventEmitter:

```
@Input() private uploadSuccess: EventEmitter<boolean>;
```

Additionally in childComponent.ts subscribe to the event:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.uploadSuccess) {
   this.getEvent.subscribe(data => {
     // Do something in the childComponent after parent emits the event.
   });
  }
}
```

Parent Component

In ParentComponent.html

```
<child-component  [uploadSuccess] = "uploadSuccess" > </child-component>
```

In ParentComponent.ts

```
private uploadSuccess: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  onImageUploadSuccess(event) {
    console.log('Image Upload succes');
    if (event.code === 'OK' && this.maxUploadLimit > 0) {
      this.galleryImagesCount = this.galleryImagesCount + 1;
      this.maxUploadLimit = this.maxUploadLimit - 1;
     }

      // The parent emits the event which was given as `@Input` variable to the child- 
   component
     this.uploadSuccess.emit(true);
   }
```